# how can I change the contents of /proc/product_name_extra?

Tags: root-access, kernel, amazon-kindle

I have a rooted device and need to change the contents of /proc/product_name_extra from Prod to Eng. I have tried cp, mv, echo, and vi. I get IO error most commonly and no matter what perms I set I cannot edit the file. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

`/proc` isn't a real filesystem, so the 'files' in it can't be changed by normal means. Rather, it gives file-like access to the system state. The only way to change what it reports is to actually change the system: in this case, that means flashing your device with an *engineering* ROM instead of a *production* ROM.

Comment: Damn. That's actually what I am attempting to do, but in order to flash the engineering files, the updater script checks this files value for "Eng" instead of "Prod"